# maxDate datepicker not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I'm trying to set a range in my `datepicker` with an 18 year minimum age. So when you click it it shouldn't say 2015 but it should be the year 2015 - 18.

My input:

```
<input class="form-control" id="BIRTHDAY" data-type="date" data-required="true" 
       name="BIRTHDAY" data-min="~(FORMATDATETIME(DATEADD('yyyy', -100, GETDATE()),'%d-%m-%Y'))~" 
       data-max="~(FORMATDATETIME(DATEADD('yyyy', -18, GETDATE()),'%d-%m-%Y'))~" value="~BIRTHDAY~" 
       maxlength="10" data-sim-mask="date">
```

Notice:

`data-min` does work, the minimum is 1915 however the `data-max` doesn't work. It still shows 2015. There is a validation that says you have to be 18 years but I want default settings already to be correct.

Datepicker I'm using
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: What datepicker do you use? Is it the one from bootstrap or is it a jquery pugin or something else?

Comment: And which one? Can you give a link?

Comment: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**
using javascript you could do the following. [Jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/8hnxn120/1/)

```
$('#BIRTHDAY').datetimepicker({
    minDate: '-2015/9/15', //set min date
    maxDate: '2015/9/28' //set max date
});
```

Comment: That's the solution I've seen when searching but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

You did not include the datepicker library

so add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

to your `<head>`

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/exAMc/321/)